# WCF service access from client application not working in windows container

Tags: c#, docker, wcf, docker-container

I have a WCF service that is hosted on localhost. This WCF service runs in the background to support another C# application that accesses that service. The communication works when the background is accessed locally from my local machine.
But when I try to containerize the entire setup of the background service and C# application, It starts throwing an error inside the WCF service i.e the proxy class.

I am getting the following eror:

> Communication Exception on GetDCP, Ex: Server stack trace:    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message
> reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version,
> FaultConverter faultConverter)   at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
> operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)   at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
> Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
> Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)   at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
> methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)   at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
> message) Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
> reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)   at
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
> msgData, Int32 type)   at DPCS.GetDCP(String toolName)   at
> DPCSFormClient.MainForm.StartSessionAndGetDCP(Object entity,
> DPCSClient& clientBatch, List`1& svidNameList) in
> C:\tfs\E3\DPCS\DPCSFormClient\MainForm.cs:line 184

This is how my config file looks like:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netNamedPipeBinding>
            <binding name="NetNamedPipeBinding_DPCS" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000" sendTimeout="00:05:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="1310700" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="1310700">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="1310700" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
              <security mode="None">
                <transport protectionLevel="None"/>
              </security>
            </binding>
        </netNamedPipeBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/Intel/E3/DPCSService" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetNamedPipeBinding_DPCS" contract="DPCS" name="NetNamedPipeBinding_DPCS">
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And this is how my proxy class looks like:

```
public interface ABCD
{
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://prox.A.ABCD/XYZ/StartSession", ReplyAction="http://prox.A.ABCD/XYZ/StartSessionResponse")]
    [System.ServiceModel.FaultContractAttribute(typeof(prox.A.ABCD.E3Fault), Action="http://prox.A.ABCD/Fault", Name="Fault", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/prox.A.ABCD")]
    void StartSession(string sessionXML);
    
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(IsInitiating=false, Action="prox.A.ABCD/XYZ/GetCon", ReplyAction="prox.A.ABCD/XYZ/DPCS/GetConResponse")]
    [System.ServiceModel.FaultContractAttribute(typeof(prox.A.ABCD.Fault), Action="http://prox.A.ABCD/Fault", Name="Fault", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/prox.A.ABCD")]
    string GetCon(string toolName);
```

only adding some part of code

Comment: You can use try-catch to catch CommunicationException.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/expected-exceptions

Comment: I looked at your code and it's better to set the contract property to the fully qualified name.For example: `contract="namespace.IMyService"`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Lan. I have added the try catch but it still throws the same error.